# Install python package from GitHub into Anaconda on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pycharm, anaconda

I need to install [this package located on GitHub](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange) into Anaconda enviroment. How can I achieve this?

Comment: sorry, stackoverflow ate the protocol:  
`pip install https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/tarball/master`

Comment: @cel how is it, that it works with `pip install` for anaconda interpreter? does `pip install` install the package for all interpreters in my system globally?

Comment: No, each interpreter has its own pip, also the one shipped with anaconda. You have as many versions of pip as you have interpreters. When you pip install you install the package only for one interpreter - the one this pip version belongs to.

Comment: And how did my system know that I called pip for Anaconda? I also have default python 2.7 and 3.5 interpreters. Is it because in my `$PATH` variable there is only `/home/user_name/anaconda3/bin` ?

Comment: it selects the pip that has highest priority in your path, you can use `which -a pip` to see all pip binaries in your path. The one in the first line is the one that's selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the latest version from github with pip using

```
pip install https://github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>/tarball/<branch-name>
```

in your case this would be:

```
pip install https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/tarball/master
```